Close keyboard in M3 ModalBottomSheet on BackHandler without closing the ModalBottomSheet
I have a TextField in ModalBottomSheet.
If i open the TextField and focus on it, i cannot close either the textField or the ModalBottomSheet.
I've seen some GoogleBugFixe, but no one is working even when i'm upgrading to the latest version of every libraries.
This is a weird behaviour.
Can someone help me please ?
ps : I have OnBackGestureEnabled = true
BackHandler(keyboardIsOpen) {
    if (keyboardIsOpen)
        localFocus.clearFocus()
}


if (openBottomSheet) {
    ModalBottomSheet(
        onDismissRequest = { openBottomSheet = false },
        sheetState = bottomSheetState,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 12.dp, topEnd = 12.dp),
        containerColor = White,
        contentWindowInsets = { WindowInsets(0) }
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 4.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                    .size(150.dp),
                colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                    containerColor = uiState.spaceColor
                ),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp)
            ) {
                uiState.spaceBitmap?.let {
                    Image(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(6.dp)
                            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(6.dp)),
                        bitmap = it.asImageBitmap(),
                        contentDescription = "Image Space",
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                    )
                }
                if (uiState.spaceBitmap == null) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            modifier = Modifier.size(60.dp),
                            imageVector = uiState.spaceIcon ?: Icons.Rounded.Kitchen,
                            contentDescription = uiState.spaceIcon?.name ?: Icons.Rounded.Kitchen.name,
                            tint = uiState.spaceColor.generateOnColor()
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer12()
            SpaceModifyTextField(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clearFocusOnKeyboardDismiss(),
                query = uiState.spaceName,
                hint = "Entrez un nom",
                localFocusManager = localFocusManager,
                onQueryChanged = spaceDetailsViewModel::setSpaceName
            )
            Spacer8()
            IconListRow(
                isPremium = uiState.isPremiumActive,
                spaceColor = uiState.spaceColor,
                selectedIcon = uiState.spaceIcon,
                launchCamera = {
                    localFocusManager.clearFocus()
                    spaceDetailsViewModel.launchCamera(true)
                },
                onPremiumFeature = toPremium,
                setSpaceIcon = {
                    localFocusManager.clearFocus()
                    spaceDetailsViewModel.setSpaceIcon(it)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

